# Icon in browser tab

Tags: html, favicon

I made a game in Silverlight and I want that while the game runs in the browser, the tab of the game will be with the icon's game.
for example when you open the Google website you see the google's icon on the tab.

Thanx

Answer (score 2):

That's called a 'favicon' and you can find instructions [here](http://www.htmlbasix.com/favicon.shtml) to add it to your site. It has nothing to do with Silverlight though. So you have to add it to your webpage (i.e. index.html)

```
<link rel="SHORTCUT ICON" href="http://www.yourdomain.com/name_of_icon.ico">
```

Comment: Thanx ,but I didnt create a website, just a silverlight application, so I dont have any HTML file

Comment: The Silverlight application runs in the browser. So there is a webpage which hosts the silverlight application.